# WCF POST Method returning "Method not allowed"

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf

I have the following WCF web service:

I defined in IService1

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    string testSer();
```

and In Service1.svc

```
public string testSer()
{
return "test";
}
```

I am calling the web service, from C# winForm application like this:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/webservices/Service1.svc/");


            var request = new RestRequest("testSer", Method.POST);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
            MessageBox.Show(content);
```

The response returned is "Method Not Allowed". If I change the method type to "GET" it works.

If I tried to call the "POST" method from the browser the response returned is "Method Not Allowed"

My config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
      <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=sa;Password=111;" />
    </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>

      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"  contract="IMetadataExchange" />  
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="jsonp" name="jsonService" contract="WcfService3.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="soapService" contract="WcfService3.IService1" />

      </service>
    </services> 
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="soapService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonp" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="False" />
          <!--<enableWebScript />-->
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  policyVersion="Policy15" />/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

 <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping> 

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

    <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**EDIT**
When I tried to test the service using WCF Test Client (That comes with Microsoft visual studio) I recieve the following error :

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from https://www.example.net/cms/Service1.svc/TestSer If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: https://www.example.net/cms/Service1.svc/TestSer Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://www.example.net/cms/Service1.svc/TestSer'. The content type application/json; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 34 bytes of the response were: '{"testSerResult":"test-1 service"}'.HTTP GET Error URI: https://www.example.net/cms/Service1.svc/TestSer There was an error downloading 'https://www.example.net/cms/Service1.svc/TestSer'. The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Since you are just returning a string with the current OperationContract, you'd rather make a GET request than a POST request.

Comment: Yes, however, what if I need to send a JSON string(about 500 chars or more) and return also a JSON string, will GET be applicable?

Comment: It actually depends on what you do with the data that is being sent. If the data is processed or/and persisted (saved into database) you should use POST. If the data is only used for query and fetching data, then you're good with GET.

Comment: I need to save it in the database if I changed the operation contract to
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "*")] it works, but what does * means?

Comment: It means that specific operation is allowing all HTTP request methods (GET, POST, DELETE; OPTIONS ....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks you all and especially for @jalison-evora for his help.

The error was due to NGinX configuration.

Please check this link

[WCF Service Method Not Allowed When Using WebsiteName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767539/wcf-service-method-not-allowed-when-using-websitename/48768827#48768827)

Answer (score 0):

change `webconfig` like the code below

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<modules>
<remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
            <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: The server now returns: An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.Please note that I am calling the web service from winForm App

Answer (score 0):

Decorate your Operation contract with

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
```

And in your Web Config should be like this:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <client />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="False" />
          <!--<enableWebScript />-->
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="soapService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="jsonp" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonp" name="jsonService" contract="WcfService3.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="metadata" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services> 
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is your data returned from the post endpoint:

[image]

Comment: @HassanShouman didn't worked? Are you sure you decorated operation contract with webinvoke and you checked the config? I replicated the same environment and the same service and its work.

Comment: hello No did not work! Yes I decorated the operation conract. I posted my config file in the question

Comment: @HassanShouman I cant find any problem in your code. I think you are trying to access the POST method from browser. Is not possible to access a  POST method endpoint from browser, because POST method have a body to which the GET method does not need and does not have.

Comment: @HassanShouman did you see my last update with your code working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164963/discussion-between-hassan-shouman-and-jailson-evora).