# WCF Service Method Not Allowed When Using WebsiteName

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf, soap

I have the following service contract

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]
        List<Myobject> GetAll();
```

When I call the service method using the IP of the server (An online server) it works, but when I call it using the name of the website it does not work, it returns "Method Not Allowed".
The Url of the server is of format "https://www.example.com/myweb (This is not working)
While for example xxxx.xx.xx.xx/myweb is working.
Please note the these are not the same server, they are two different servers.

where https://www.example.com/myweb is redirected using an HttpProxy (NginX), to
 xxxx.xx.xx.xx/myweb

Comment: Sounds like an NginX configuration issue.

Comment: @mjwills I suspect in that, but do not know what to do

Answer (score 0):

The error was generated by NginX
Adding this statement

```
# To allow POST on static pages
        error_page  405     =200 $uri;
```

to the nginX config file solved the error.

Check this link to have more info:

http://invalidlogic.com/2011/04/12/serving-static-content-via-post-from-nginx/